How can I update the token logo of our coin on Phantom?
We updated the token logo metadata over a month ago for Solanacorn (ca: 6DSqVXg9WLTWgz6LACqxN757QdHe1sCqkUfojWmxWtok; https://solscan.io/token/6DSqVXg9WLTWgz6LACqxN757QdHe1sCqkUfojWmxWtok) but the old logo is still displaying on Raydium, Phantom, and Jupiter. It's been updated on Solscan, Coingecko, and other platforms.
Is there a way to "push" this update to these apps so that the correct logo is showing?
Thanks in advance!

The image is cached either on your end or their. You can try a hard refresh of your tab in the browser. If the image doesn't change then it's cached at their end and you'd need to get in touch with them and ask them to refresh their cache
